# Cuando nos referimos a una red punto a punto ¿Solo es unicast?

Tags: redes, net

tenía una duda teorica que me gustaría si me la pudieran aclarar.

Yo soy programador web, pero me estoy adentrando al mundo de las redes... el caso es que encuentro el concepto red punto a punto y me entra la duda, dada la definición de esta (enlace punto a punto) y es ¿La red punto a punto solo puede ser unicast? Es decir que UNICAST es que va de un unico emisor a un unico receptor.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

### Respuesta rápida

[PTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_(telecommunications)) es un termino de arquitectura de red

[UNICAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicast) es una metodología de transmisión de paquetes a destinos

Una red con arquitectura `PTP` puede trasmitir de cualquiera forma, sea `uni-broad-any-multi cast`, dependiendo de la configuración que se le haya dado.

### PTP

El termino punto a punto - `PTP` - se refiere a la tipología de las conexiones y nodos en una red. Podríamos definir ese tipo de enlace que solo une a dos nodos. Muchas veces eses nodos representan dos grandes redes cuya interconexión de las mismas se hace por `PTP`.

También existe el término PTMP, punto a multipunto, lo que seria el tipico punto de acceso que da cobertura a varios dispositivos mobiles.

Ese tipo de conexiones utilizadas con [`protocolo IP`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_de_internet) trabajan con todas las metodologia posibles del mismo, como [`anycast`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difusi%C3%B3n_por_proximidad), [`broadcast`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast), [`multicast`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidifusi%C3%B3n), [`unicast`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidifusi%C3%B3n)

#### [PPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol)

También existe el protocolo `PPP`, no confundir con `PTP`, se trata del `protocolo punto a punto`. Al tratarse de un protocolo, estamos hablando también de arquitectura de red pero en términos de aplicación. Sirve para darle al [`SO`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_operativo) un `endpoint` directo a otro dispositivo , en otras palabras establecer una `VPN`.